# Routes folder in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When you create an Express application you get a routes folder. All routes are registered in the app.js file. However the logic on what happens is located in the files of the routes folder. Is this a synonym for controller folders in other frameworks? Is this the location of where you should add the request/response logic?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, is kind of the same thing as a controller folder. IMO, you better use different files as you would with controllers in another language because when the application is getting bigger it's hard to understand the code when all the request/response logic is in the same file.

Example :

**app.js** :

```
var express = require('express'),
    employees = require('./routes/employee');

var app = express();

app.get('/employees', employees.findAll);
app.get('/employees/:id', employees.findById);

app.listen(80);
```

**routes/employee.js** :

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    res.send([{name:'name1'}, {name:'name2'}, {name:'name3'}]);
};

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    res.send({id:req.params.id, name: "The Name", description: "description"});
};
```

Comment: I think the main difference is that other frameworks may use the folder hierarchy to define which controllers respond to which routes.  In express, the folder is just a place to dump the routes definitions to clean up the code.